# IntelliJ Idea bundle JS files

Tags: intellij-idea, gruntjs, typescript, intellij-plugin, tsc

I am working on a huge project where i am using Java, TypeScript, Jade and Less.
To compile the project, i am using Maven (Java) + Grunt( TS, Jade, LESS). Grunt is called from maven, because maven drives whole project (include backend). With grunt everthing works perfect, but i want to have realtime compilation in idea, on ctrl+s command of frontend. I am using FileWatchers plugin for that, but there is a problem. 
My html page is referencing to bundle.js file, that is compile over grunt. All TypeScript files are compiled to JS files and bundle.js file. Problem is, that i am not able to compile bundle.js realtime. I have tried to set an argument to tsc. Sth like

```
         tsc -out bundle.js "**/*.ts"
```

Problem is, that tsc doesnt support regular expression. I have found some solution, but all of them requires some definition of files, that need to be done by external tool and werent automatic.

I dont want to the this options :

```
         tsc -out bundle.js @FileWithTSFiles.txt
         tsc -out bundle.js main.ts hello.ts helloWorld.ts
```

One more solution is propably possible, but don't know all necessary informations. I have got an idea to use FileWatchers plugin this way (like an argument write sth like)

```
         tsc -out bundle.js $MacroToListAllFilesInProject$
```

because some macros are available here. Problem is, that i need to define custom macro to list the files, and i am not able to find the place to do that.

**Same problem with LESS Files.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grunt( TS, Jade, LESS).

If you are using `grunt-ts` simply use a target like :

```
        dev: {     
            src: ['./**/*.ts'],
            out: './bundle.js',
        },
```

Reference : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts

I'd like to point out that when using `--out` you should use a `reference` file to determine the order of the generated javascript https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#javascript-generation-and-ordering

Comment: i am using that already, but it doesnt work on ctrl+s or does? :)

Comment: You need to use `grunt-contrib-watch` if you want to run `grunt-ts` + other tasks on ctrl+s. see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#examples